# How to modify the default value of a select dropdown without using inline javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

In a Chrome extension, Google does not allow us to add inline javascript to popup.html. Thus, the only option is to link to an external script.

I have the following:

**script.js:**

```
if (localStorage.getItem("mySelectValue") === null) { 
    document.write("choose a value"); 
}
else {
    document.write(localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue'));
}
```

**popup.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mySelectValue').change(function(){
         localStorage.setItem('mySelectValue', $(this).val());
         $('#mySelectValue').value(localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue'));
    });
});
```

**popup.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>

<select id="mySelectValue">
   <option name="" value=""><script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script></option>
       <option value="first" name="first">first</option>
       <option value="second" name="second">second</option>
       <option value="third" name="third">third</option>
</select>
```

This code successfully displays the text but I can't add in a script to the value in this manner. So how can I do the same method to define the given value in local storage also as the value?

Comment: jQuery has no `.value()` method. However, it has `.val()`

Comment: In popup.js, you should search for an <option> whose value corresponds to the stored value, and set it as the selected option.

Comment: @Johan, regardless, the script works fine for me, it's not the problem. The problem is doing the same thing as I did for the text in the first option of the select form, and do that for the **`value`** field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, you can do the following:

```
$("#mySelectValue option[value='"+localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue')+"']").attr("selected","selected");
```

This basically finds the `option` with the same value you get from `localStorage.getItem('mySelectValue')` and makes it selected by default.

Comment: It didn't work, but as it turns out I didn't need to do it! :D

Comment: I'll accept because it's the only answer even though it doesn't work.